# Why hover css properties not working when using SortableJs

Tags: css, angular14, sortablejs

I have used SortableJs for drag and droping a table row into a div using angular14

The issue i am facing is when dragging a row and hovering over an element, the element's hover css properties are not applying.

HTML

```
<tbody  [sortablejs]="(data)"
                  [sortablejsOptions]="sortableOptions" >
```

Component.ts sortOptions

```
public sortableOptions: SortablejsOptions = {
        group: {somedata
 },
        handle: '.handle',
        onUpdate: this.priorityChanged.bind(this),
        onAdd: this.onAdd.bind(this),
        onMove: this.onMove.bind(this),
        onEnd: this.onEnd.bind(this)
    };
```

```
.treeDiv:hover {
  background: red !important;
  border: none;
}
```

Hover is working in one of my another component. Am I missing any options to pass in sortableOptions

Comment: Where is the class `treeDiv` in the HTML/DOM?